# Using rigify armature, how do I create a control for eye color?

Tags: rigging, armature, color, rigify

I am using a rigify armature for my character and all works great, but I also want to create an extra control for the eye colors, Like for example to make a nurbs circle that I can move to left and right which will modify the eye textures "Color", could someone give me step by step walkthrough?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any object to be the controller. Then add drivers to the RGB component of your material. (Right click the RGB color box and click Add Driver). Then for the eyes, go into the Drivers Editor and select the Drier to be of type Averaged Value. For the object, have it be the object you want to control the color. Set type to Y rotation. You can do this for R G B and A. Then when you move/rotate your Nurbs circle (or whatever object you want, the color will change (need to be in rendered view).

Here is a [.blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51096) with a simple set up. If this doesn't quite make sense, let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, will try what you said, but due to internet issues, will most likely delay to respond back.